# How to run multiple javascript file in replit (online ide)?

Tags: javascript

How to run multiple javascript files in replit (online IDE) ?
Does it exits in replit IDE?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create multiple files. Choose the file type correctly.